# How to pass live video stream from webRTC/aiortc to python for face recognition

Tags: python, flask, deployment, webrtc, video-streaming

I'm working on deployment of a face recognition Flask application with nginx and gunicorn. It works fine on local host but I've encountered an issue accessing a remote user's media/camera since openCV cannot get the permission to do so. I've tried out different approaches including Javascript which is the most suitable but the problem with that is I have not found a way to pass the video stream to the face recognition functions. My most recent discovery aiortc looks promising as it is a wrapper around Javascript's `getUserMedia` but I'm having trouble installing and running it.
I ran `pip3 install aiortc` but when I try to run something like `video = aiortc.MediaPlayer('/dev/video0', format='v4l2', options={'video_size':'640x480'})` I get the message `AttributeError: module 'aiortc' has no attribute 'MediaPlayer'`.'

I've come across WebRTC which I've tried but to no avail. How can I get a live video stream to pass to python so as to conduct face recognition? I would highly appreciate any help. I'm sorry if the issue is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The example at https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/main/examples/server uses `MediaPlayer` and would be a good starting point for what you need, I think.